# Setting up a Developers' environment in a second domain

Tags: linux, containers, virtual-machine, windows-server

This may be the wrong forum to ask this question. If so, I'd love links or suggestions as to where to post it.

Background:

In our current environment, developers have Windows desktop machines with decent though not crazy specs and wired Ethernet.  Enough to develop, compile, test, commit, etc.

We'll be moving to a new environment (not our choice!) where the desktops are replaced by wifi-only laptops and no fixed workstations.  That means, e.g. a dev cannot start a long-job at 5 pm, go home while it runs and have it finish by 8 am the next day, since the wifi connection will be broken.  This is an issue for us.  An additional complication is that the work is often cross-AD-domain.

Questions:

We're brainstorming other options.  Some ideas that have come up:

1. keep the old desktops, put 'em in a closet and let the devs RDP to them (mostly Windows, a few Linux via ssh).  Wire the desktops to a second domain
2. put in a beefy server or two and allow multiple concurrent logins.  Install the required software etc. Wire the servers to a second domain
3. Set up a VM per dev on a suitable host in the second domain
4. Containers?

Is #4 even possible?  Can you spin up a container that you can remote into in GUI mode in either Linux or Windows?

What other options are worth looking at?  What have others done? Trying to learn from others' experiences and not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Probably better asked on https://superuser.com. Any of those options is better than trying to make a long-running job that requires a network run with a network that's frequently down. You'll find a whole range of opinions about whether it's better to develop on a desktop/laptop or on a slice of a powerful server.

Comment: posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1315174/setting-up-new-windows-dev-environment-with-connection-to-second-ad-domain) as per suggestion. Thanks!